# No se ejecuta la función de JS desde el HTML

Tags: javascript, html5, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

estoy tratando de hacer un formulario en Google App Script y estoy viendo que desde el html cuando quiero ejecutar la función `appendData` no se ejecuta y/o no le comparte bien los parámetros.

Les dejo mi código
**HTML**

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>


<div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="name" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="name">Name</label>
        </div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="tel" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="tel">Tel</label>
        </div>
  </div>


<button id="boton" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" name="action">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
  </button>


    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

   <script> 
         var nameBox = document.getElementById("name");
         var phoneBox = document.getElementById("tel");
         document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", addRecord);

         function addRecord(){
             var name = nameBox.value;
             var phone = phoneBox.value;

         if(name.trim().length == 0 || phone.trim().length == 0){
            google.script.run.errorMessage();
         } else {
             var data = {
                     name: nameBox.value,
                     phone: phoneBox.value
             };
             google.script.run.appendData(data);
             nameBox.value = "";
             phonebox.value = "";
         }
        }
      </script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

**Google Script**

```
function showUserForm(){
var template = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"); //createTemplateFromFile("index");
//var html = template.evaluate();
template.setTitle("Title")

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(template, "Visualización de encuestas");
}

function appendData(data){
     var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data")
     ws.appendRow([data.name, data.phone]);
}

function errorMessage(){
    Browser.msgBox("Name & Phone are required!");
}
```

Comment: Siempre revisa la consola de tu navegador, posiblemente tengas un error del tipo Undefined addRecord();

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript es en cascada, va de arriba hacia abajo.
Entonces:

```
var nameBox = document.getElementById("name");
     var phoneBox = document.getElementById("tel");
     // la función no ha sido definida aquí aún
     document.getElementById("boton").addEventListener("click", addRecord); 
     // Aquí se define
     function addRecord(){
         var name = nameBox.value;
         var phone = phoneBox.value;

     if(name.trim().length == 0 || phone.trim().length == 0){
        google.script.run.errorMessage();
     } else {
         var data = {
                 name: nameBox.value,
                 phone: phoneBox.value
         };
         google.script.run.appendData(data);
         nameBox.value = "";
         phonebox.value = "";
     }
    }
```

La solución es simplemente declarar la función antes de añadir el listener a "boton"